# ECS task definition versioning

Tags: amazon-ecs

We have two clusters for deploying ECS tasks - staging and production. When registering new task definition, in container definition we set `ENVIRONMENT` variable (can be "PRODUCTION" or "STAGING"). This creates duplicate task definitions with just "environment" values being different in container definition. So we end up with task definition revisions looking like this:

```
task:5
task:4
task:3
task:2
task:1
```

And it's hard to tell from the glance which revision has "STAGING" as environment variable and which one is "PRODUCTION". Since our deployments are automated, it's not that big of a deal, but I was wondering how others handle situation like this. Maybe there's a better way?

Comment: Usually environment segragation is done at AWS account level.

Comment: Thanks for reply @Andrey. I like the idea of building Docker image once, testing it in staging and "promoting" it to prod. With separate AWS accounts it seems we would have separate ECRs and would end up building different images for staging and for prod.

Comment: Not necessarily. You can configure ECR policy to allow ECS from production account to pull images from Dev/stage account. Some places I worked in, there was was even a separate account just to host ECR.

Comment: Interesting. I don't think we'll be changing our AWS accounts setup (we split by responsibility, not by environment) right now, but I will keep it in mind. Thanks for the insights @Andrey